# vmware powercli install software

Tags: powershell

Is it possible that I can install .exe or .msi to my vm's using powercli.

I want to use an installer then install it on the vm I specify.
I also want to do this quiet so im not seeing the installer running and no clicking next.
I just want to say this is my path put it to this path on this vm and install it quiet.

Comment: Why powercli and not just regular PowerShell? Also refrain from using comments like _anyone can help me_ as they are liable to get flagged and are not constructive.

Comment: im using powershell but the module from vmware when powercli is installed is needed with this i think.

Comment: I just mean why not use something simple like [`Invoke-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx). PowerCLI is good for VM management but I am not sure about any limitations it would have talking to the OS.

Comment: im using the invoke-command but i dont know how to use it to push the installer up its setting up an proces in the vm but its not doing anything with it.

Comment: Isn't this what products like [System Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/system-center-2012-r2/) are designed to handle for you?

Comment: is System Center possible to push installers to an vm using vmware?

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to go through PowerCLI that (and so through vCenter), you can use the cmdlet Invoke-VMScript to "inject" a script or scriptblock in the guest OS.

For example :

```
Invoke-VMScript -VM <YourVM> -ScriptText "msiexec /i path/to/your/package.msi /q" -GuestUser "YourUsername" -GuestPassword "YourPassword"
```

Comment: yeah that is what im using but its only creating an proces and not installing it im using install_flash_player_17_active_x.msi for the test if its working but im not seeing anyting then starting an process

Comment: anything you could think of how to fix that?